# How to make html selection with independent two columns?

Tags: html, select, drop-down-menu

I want to make a 'year' and 'month' selection on the mobile web using HTML selection list with independent 2 columns. Selection one doesn't affect the other selection like iPhone alarm setting.

Also, I want to make a drop-down using one click (etc. I don't want to let the people click twice to open each year and month selection.)

I've searched google and I couldn't find the answer. Anyone would help? Thank you very much!!

[image: ihpone alarm]

[image]